# Obtain a tree from a graph by specifing root and leaves

Tags: java, jung, jgrapht

I am looking at both jgrapht and jung but I seem to not find any method to allow me to do what I'd like.

I have a graph and, by specifing a root node and some leaves, I'd like to obtain a tree from it or at least an error if this is not possible.

Both jgraphT and jung seem to have alghoritms to obtain a minimum spanning tree out of a graph, but the obtained tree is random, no one assures me that a given node will be a leaf and another will be a relay....

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you saying that you want an algorithm to take as input a Graph, a list of nodes, and a root, and to either return a tree if you can interpret that Graph as such a tree with that root and those leaves?  Or can it be a subgraph (spanning tree) of that Graph, that is, do you have to use all the edges of the original Graph or not?

Comment: No, I don't need to use all the edges of the original graph...I have a graph, in this graph I specify which node is my root and which nodes are my leaves, rest of the nodes are simple relays. I want a tree which allows me, from the root, to reach every leaf. I don't need to use all nodes or edges, what's important is that the root and all leaves are part of the final tree.

Comment: Is it acceptable if there are leaves that you didn't specify that are part of the final tree, or must all leaves be specified?  Is it acceptable if you don't use all the nodes of the original graph (suppose you have a graph with several connected components, or your "root" has a parent that can't be reached from the root)?  What overall problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: You specify what nodes are leaves and root, not marked nodes can be used as relays or not (ie. if a straight connection between a root and a leaf already exists there is no need to include an intermediate node). I am trying to create a tree out of a network (which would be an undirected and connected graph), that is to get a network with no loops in which each leaf node is reachable from the root. I'd save somewhere unused links/nodes so to achieve some redundancy in the case one link or node falls (in that case I'd just repeat the alghoritm with remaining nodes to get a new tree if possible)

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the problem with just one leaf, then this devolves to the question "is there a  walk that starts at the root and ends at the leaf that visits every other node at least once?"

Which sounds an awful lot like the Longest Path problem...which is NP-hard.  (And I don't think adding more leaves helps.  :) )

I can think of heuristic approaches (and of ways to prove for a specific graph, or choice of root/leaves, that the problem has no solution) but I suspect that in general you're going to have to use an exhaustive search approach, something like this:

1. Remove all outgoing edges from the leaves.
2. If you can't reach everything from the root (BFS will do here), there's no solution.
3. Start traversing the graph from the root.
4. At each step:
   If you haven't reached all the leaves and there are no more edges to traverse, there's no solution.
   If you've reached all the leaves and all the nodes have been visited, you're done.
   Otherwise, traverse an edge you haven't traversed yet.